# WordPress front page display issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I've developed my theme locally and I have the Reading Settings > Front page displays > Front page displays > Your latest posts.

This would then mean the template file would be home.php and this all works fine on my local machine. Though when I push this to my live site and have the same settings the front-page.php file is being displayed even though I deleted it and cleared my cache.

You can view the site here: www.eatsleepkayak.com

The home page should be displaying a blog feed not the current quotes landing page.

Im not sure why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

After move live Permalink re-save. 
Note: .htaccess should be writable.

or create template file and assign to any other page. Use this page as front page.